# Gathering sent events from UITextField

Tags: ios, uitextfield

How can i gather `sent events` from a UITextField in one place or am i forced to create outlets and actions for every single event i intend to use?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got your question correctly you need to get the text from UITextField when this UITextField loose focus (user taps elsewhere). To achieve this you need:

1. Declare your class as  (in yourClassName.h
   file)
2. Implement in yourClassName.m file this method:

   ```
   - (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
       NSString *someStringOrWhateverYouNeed = textField.text;   
   }
   ```

Any time user will press return button on keyboard your class will have a notification and call this method.

In case if you need to gather event from multiple UITextFields you can mark all your textField with specific tags and create one IBAction like this:

```
- (IBAction)getTextFieldEvent:(id)sender {
    UITextField *currentTextField = (UITextField *)sender;
    switch (currentTextField.tag) {
        case 1:
            // some code here for textField with tag = 1
            break;
        case 2:
            // some code here for textField with tag = 2
            break;
        case 3:
            // some code here for textField with tag = 3
            break;
        default:
            // some default code here
            break;
    }
}
```

For different event types I can suggest to create different IBAction's. If you do not need to change UITextField's properties (e.g. font etc.) then you do not really need IBOutlets.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Im mostly interested in how different event types can be handled without creating IBActions, but i understand theres no workaround and i have to make all these IBActions?

Comment: IBAction is only proper way to handle control's events :)

Answer (score 0):

Do another IBAction connection with the same name.  Then erase the duplicate method.  Both textfields will be connected to the same IBAction method.